# Get an entry from Map which has objects as keys, with partial comparison

Tags: javascript, object

I have a Map generated from an arbitrary array of objects. An example entry of the Map: `{ id: 2, parent: 1 } => { id: 2, parent: 1, type: 'any' }`.

Now say there is a function that receives the id as a parameter and has to return a value with matching id. From what I understand, the .get method of the Map requires a full object to compare to.

```
getItem(id) {
    //always returns null
    return this.treeMap.get({id: id}) || null
  }
```

How could I get an entry from the said Map provided with only one key value to compare to? TIA!

Comment: "*From what I understand, the .get method of the Map requires a full object to compare to.*" not just "the full" object. It needs *literally* the same object, not another object with the same data as the original key.

Comment: As VLAZ has already said, with `getItem(id) {`, `id` should be the original key object and should passed directly to `.get`

Comment: @VLAZ I see. Any other way I could achieve direct access to object entries with specific values in the Map object then?

Comment: @NPavlov maybe I have an idea. Do you only have a strict subset of what you want to be checking? In your example, the key has `id` and `parent` - would you only want to fetch by either both or just `id`? Because if you try to look up an object by just `parent` you might have multiple entries with the same one, so a strategy to handle that would be needed.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah, I need to be able to get specific items, children and all parents of an item up to the root. That's why I've included these entries into the keys of the Map (that's the first thing that came to mind). I've got that implemented using plain objects but now refactoring

Comment: Link to jsfiddle with the logic implementation using plain objects: https://jsfiddle.net/ebxfyvgo/